# SecurityException on Intent.ACTION_VIEW while trying to open PDF

Tags: android, android-intent, storage-access-framework

I ask a user to choose a PDF document using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. The intent returns a content URI.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_LOCAL_ONLY, true);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
```

The content URI is in the format - 
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2FSample%20PDF.pdf

Now, I want the user to access the same document again - later on, from a separate activity. So I write the following code -

```
Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    pdfIntent.setData(document.getLocalUri());
                    pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    mContext.startActivity(pdfIntent);
```

But I get the following error -

```
java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10197 does not have permission to content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw%3A%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDownload%2FSample%20PDF.pdf [user 0]; you could obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you declared the permission in manifest ?

Comment: Add this line on your manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Most likely, your problem lies here:

> I want the user to access the same document again - later on, from a separate activity

The activity that requested and received the `Uri` to the content has rights to that content... but nothing else of your app does. That includes other components in your current process any any components in future processes.

If this is a separate activity, but still in the same app instance (i.e., your process has not been terminated since when you got the `Uri`), you need to pass the rights to that content to the separate activity. Pass the `Uri` via the "data" facet of the `Intent` and use `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` as you are doing with the `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`. See [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.8/Documents/Durable), where I use `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to grant rights to a `Service` to be able to read the content.

If your intention is to persist the `Uri` value itself (e.g., store it as a string in a database) and use it in the future, you can instead use `takePersistableUriPermission()` on `ContentResolver` to request long-term access to the content. This should succeed (I don't know of any scenario where you're immediately denied access). You should have access until something drastic happens to the content, such as the user deleting it.

Comment: Thanks. takePersistableUriPermission() was what I needed. I just came across your blog - https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html - cleared up a lot of the URI mess for me :)